# How to safely remove SMD piezo-buzzer from QI charger?

Tags: surface-mount, piezo-buzzer

I have a QI charger which goes by title "Solomon SQI-500". Whenever device is placed on the charger last makes annoying beep. I suppose I located this buzzer at the board of device and there it is on the photo below.

I want to know if I need to replace it with wire/resistor/etc to get rid of beeping.

Or in general, **How do I safely remove this buzzer?**

Pictures are clickable.

[image: Buzzer 1] [image: Buzzer 2]

Comment: Are you sure that's a buzzer, and not some part with a different purpose that that happens to make noise occasionally.  `J1`  seems like an odd designation...

Comment: I was more interested in safely removing. To be sure it won't impact using the device. Anyway I removed this piece and charger is silent now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My UPS had a similar problem so I put some hot glue over the buzzer hole, it's nice and quiet now. Failing that, if you aren't going to need the buzzer ever again, you might be able to silence it just by cutting one of the tracks with a sharp knife () assuming the track doesn't go anywhere else). Or, if you want to take an EE approach, a fine tipped soldering iron and some desoldering braid might do it, otherwise you'll need an SMD hot air gun (glorified 300'C hairdrier) and some tweezers